# cucumber speed, performance tuning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, testing, cucumber

I have profiled my feature files. I have found out that my login step takes the most time.

```
Given /^I am logged in as "(.+)"$/ do |login|
  visit path_to('the home page')
  fill_in "login", :with => login
  fill_in "password", :with => 'foobar'
  click_button "loginButton"
end
```

It takes over 5 seconds on my development box.

I want to make another step with login functionality, but without filling out the form, simply set the session, and used it in my other tests as background scenario.

```
Given /^I am logged in as "(.+)" through session$/ do |login|
  user= User.find_by_login(login)
end
```

The above step finds the user, but how I can make it stores the session, and redirects me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just avoid authenticating in the other steps, probably not what a die hard cucumber dev would say. But if you have the authentication workflow tested elsewhere, then I dont see the harm. I didn't try this, but I think the variable scope should be right.

```
Given /^I am logged in as "(.+)" through session$/ do |login|
  @user= User.find_by_login(login)
  #open the class and spike
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def current_user
      @user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Won't that replace current_user for the rest of the ruby process lifetime? If so, this could yield some really confusing results if you've got other cucumber features that _do_ really log in...

Comment: i agree, a little hacky at best. you could use an after scenario hook to reset the current_user to nil, maybe catch scenarios with a tag to know which scenarios need login steps run.